# Getting error with parametric polymorphism in c#

Tags: c#, parametric-polymorphism

In this function:

```
    public List<T> getX<T>(SPListItemCollection itemCollection, List<T> itemList, Report RO, WebpartSettings WPS, bool isFolder)
    {
        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
        {
            if (have_permissions_for_item(WPS.EDIT_MODE, item, RO))
            {
                itemList.Add(isFolder ? (T)item.Folder : (T)item);
            }
        }
        return itemList;
    }
```

which uses parametric polymorphism, I get a `itemcollection` and browse through it and add it to a list if it as the right permissions, then return the list.
The list being returned is of type `T`, so it could be of type either `SPFolder` or `SPListItem` based on my code.

The item in the for loop is already type `SPListItem`, and if `T` was of type `SPFolder` then I have to call the `.Folder` method on the item. I can't just detect this, so I had to use a helper variable to decide if I need to use it.

But the problem is even though I do this I still get an error with trying to cast it to type `T`.

`T` will be `SPFolder` when I call the `.Folder` method and `T` will be the type `SPListItem` otherwise.

Does anyone see a fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do `SPFolder` and `SPListItem` have any types in common? You'll need to constraint `T` to some common type and change `itemList` to be `List<CommonType>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `T` could in theory be any type, Visual Studio doesn't know if there's a way to cast from either type to `T`. You could try inserting an `(object)` cast:

```
itemList.Add(isFolder ? (T)(object)item.Folder : (T)(object)item);
```

As long as `T` is the correct type, you should be fine.